# Requested output format 's16le' is not a suitable output format in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, discord, discord.py

i wanna play hello.mp3 in voice but i get a error:

```
[NULL @ 000001e7f6945c80] Requested output format 's16le' is not a suitable output format
pipe:1: Invalid argument
```

code:

```py
@Bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 5, commands.BucketType.guild)
async def play(ctx, query):

    if not ctx.author.voice: # if author was not in voice
        return

    channel: discord.VoiceChannel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    cls: discord.VoiceClient = await channel.connect() # client of guild

    if not cls.is_playing():
        audio_source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source="hello.mp3")
        cls.play(source=audio_source, after=None)
```

I searched a lot about this error and did not find any results. Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244079/ffmpeg-requested-output-format-mpeg-is-not-a-suitable-output-format

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I have seen it before but I don't know how to use it